# Lollipop: Notification Icon with colour / image?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

I am having some confusion with notification icons in relation to its background.

I read that in lollipop, all colours will be translated to white and that the system only processes the alpha channel and ignoring the colour channels.

So my question is how would I go about making a notification icon similar to this: The "Marvel Comics" icon?

[image]

What exactly has to be transparent? because I am getting the same issue as shown here[image]

I have seen that the solution as described here https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/notifications.html under *Use Distinct Icons* but what if I wanted an icon just like the marvel one shown in the first image without making it just white?

Thank you for reading

Comment: You are comparing apples and oranges. Your icon is in the status bar. Their icon is in the notification tray. What does their icon look like in the status bar?

Comment: @CommonsWare, Apologies, you are right, I am so confused. So in the status bar, I need to make an icon that is all white with transparent section where my content would go?

Comment: If the Marvel icon in the status bar is all white, then what they have in the notification tray is [the "large icon"](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setLargeIcon%28android.graphics.Bitmap%29), which can be multi-color. I do not know if there is a way to get a multi-color icon in the status bar.

Comment: @CommonsWare: I suppose there is ,although Im not sure how there an app here called m indicator whose notifications in the status bar appear coloured and so is the case for the Steam app. I figured it out to be the target sdk version as the cause. Check answer

Answer (score 1):

Finally this workaround

Just change your build target sdk to 19 from 21 (or later) in your gradle file (or your manifest for eclipse users). I don't like the idea of targeting a non latest version but in order to have the a colored icon theres seems to be no other choice.

If you still wish to target latest version thenmake do with what @Commonsware suggests.